# template.php remove css and body style

Tags: php, drupal-7

Hi how do i remove the body classes that are being added body the template.php

I am using the ZEN template and ripping it apart. If you know how to get rid of the following.

```
<style>
@import url("http://localhost/~russellharrower/netcast/modules/system/system.base.css?nl30xl");
@import url("http://localhost/~russellharrower/netcast/modules/system/system.messages.css?nl30xl");
@import url("http://localhost/~russellharrower/netcast/modules/system/system.theme.css?nl30xl");
</style>
```

and `<body class>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your template.php, but you need actually to create a child theme of ZEN and override the CSS values. 
    function THEMENAME_css_alter(&$css) {
        unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.theme.css']);
        unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.base.css']);
        unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.messages.css']);
    }